# symfony2 FromBuilder multiple checkboxes from entity instead of using "choice"

Tags: symfony, checkbox, entity

How can I get multiple Cehckboxes instead a choice field in Symfony? Actually, I'm using:

```
->add('usergroups', 'entity', array('class' => 'PrUserBundle:Group','property' => 'name','required' => true))
```

This will output a select-Field..

In this case, it would be better to output checkboxes as it is easier to handle for the user.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html at, there is nothing helpful about multiple select....
Do I have to build an array and place it by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `expanded` option for `choice` and `entity` fields.

```
->add('usergroups', 'entity', array('class' => 'PrUserBundle:Group','property' => 'name','required' => true, 'expanded' => true,))
```